# Problem with joomla with photos and redirection

Tags: joomla

I deleted the pictures through the Joomla panel and I get such an error on the page as you can see in the picture. How to deal with this?

[image]

How to add redirection but without domain?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue about the pictures seems to be an issue with the component you're using, which is ***com_joomgallery*** in your case. When you delete the picture, it gets deleted but somehow its showing up in your JoomGallery image listing and so is the error.

Can you let me know from where you've deleted the photos? Was it from JoomGallery or from somewhere else?

If you haven't deleted them from JoomGallery then that's the reason for your issue, because JoomGallery database table still have those records and when it tries to list them its unable to find the thumbnails/images that you've deleted.

About your second question, how are you redirecting to external URL? If you're trying to open the external URL from an anchor tag try doing it like

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/" targe="_blank">Link</a>
```

But you're using `Route::_` to open the external URL, then don't. As `Route::_` isn't used for external links but is meant only for internal URLs. If you want to open or redirect using Joomla, then try like this

```
$url = Uri::getInstance("//www.facebook.com");
$url->setScheme("https");
$externalURL = $url->toString();
echo "<a href='$externalURL'>Link</a><br>";
```

I hope this helps.